# Google Now voice calling feature only searching local contacts, not businesses

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean, voice-command, google-now

In Google Voice Assistant on ICS I could, for example, say "Call the closest Dominos" or "Call CompUSA West Palm" and Google Voice Assistant would start to dial the correct business almost immediately.

Since I've upgraded to JB, Google Now only seems to search my contacts and sometimes brings up map locations of businesses I wish to call. This is extremely disappointing and would really like to know if anyone else is having this issue and if it can be resolved.

Comment: Also, if anyone could comment just to let me know this is not only happening to me. I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether or not this is going to help in your case, but a friend told me that if you set your language to English US (as opposed to English GB, CA, AU, NZ etc.), you get a different/better voice recognition engine.

Comment: Unfortunately, English (US) is what my phone is already set to.